# oracle change variable type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, oracle12c

i am using code first approach ,and i suppose that the default type for string in the database side is nvarchar(), but what i found is nclob which is bigger than nvarchar and i didn't figure out why.

this is part of my model :

```
  public string Name { get; set; }
    public string En_Name { get; set; }
```

and this is its configuration :

```
 this.Property(p => p.Name).HasMaxLength(200).IsOptional();
        this.Property(p => p.En_Name).HasMaxLength(50).IsOptional();
```

i need it to be nvarchar not nclob

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak the language you're using.

However, from Oracle's point of view: if a column datatype is NCLOB, you can't just *modify* it to a NVARCHAR2 (if that's what you want to do). Though, there is a way to do it. Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table test (col nclob);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values ('x');

1 row created.

SQL> alter table test modify col nvarchar2(20);
alter table test modify col nvarchar2(20)
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-22859: invalid modification of columns


SQL>
```

OK, it won't work that way. So:

- create a new column (of the NVARCHAR2 datatype)
- put NCLOB contents in there
- drop the old NCLOB column
- rename the new column into the old column's name

.

```
SQL> alter table test add col_vc nvarchar2(20);

Table altered.

SQL> update test set col_vc = dbms_lob.substr(col, 20, 1);

1 row updated.

SQL> alter table test drop column col;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table test rename column col_vc to col;

Table altered.

SQL> desc test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COL                                                NVARCHAR2(20)

SQL> select * From test;

COL
--------------------
x

SQL>
```

Now you have a NVARCHAR2 column, so - hopefully, your code will work properly.

If the above approach won't work (because you aren't allowed to modify column's datatype), I guess that someone else will have to assist.